# Delegate of subclassed NSTableView is not retained?

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nstableview, weak-references

I have a class `ETXTableView` which is a subclass of `NSTableView`. (CHANGED after comment) Its delegate is set in IB to the viewController (as is its data source).

There are four instances of this class: four tables above each other. The user can click or mouse from the one instance to the other. The code for `moveDown:` is as follows:

```
-(void)moveDown:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"self=%ld, delegate=%ld",self,self.delegate);
    lastKeyDownOrUp = 1;
    if (viewController.sectionArrayController.canSelectNext)
    {
        NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:(viewController.sectionArrayController.selectionIndex+1)];
        [self selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
    }
    else{
        [[self window] selectKeyViewFollowingView:self];
    }
    << Code to show a details panel >>;
}
```

The value for `self.delegate` is *nil* in this code. I am almost certain that is because the delegate has a weak reference.

1. Why would this reference be released? (If more information is needed, let me know)
2. How should I define the delegate in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would it be its own delegate? Normally that is another object. MVC.

Comment: You are right -- it's just a way to see if I can get the delegate to be called. After your comment I changed the situation so that there is not `setDelegate` code anymore, and I set the delegate in IB to File's Owner (which is the Controller). Delegate methods are still not called. I must be forgetting something.

Comment: Make sure the object that is delegate also declares and conforms to the NSTableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out that the controller object (let's say tVC) is a subclass of a managing view controller (managingVC). Should managingVC conform to the protocol, or tVC? Neither one works for me, so something else is wrong. But I'd rather have this out of the way :-)